# How to get StorageFolder Modified Time?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I'm writing a C# Windows Universal app that needs to be able to detect if the contents of a StorageFolder has changed.  This app will not run continuously so I do not believe I can use change notifications.

When I wrote this app in .NET using C#, I used the DirectoryInfo class and use  the LastWriteTime property.

In Windows Universal, is there a way to check the last time a StorageFolder was changed?  Or, is there a smarter way to check if the folder contents have changed when an app starts up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`StorageFolder.GetBasicPropertiesAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.getbasicpropertiesasync.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) , then [`BasicProperties.DateModified`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.basicproperties.datemodified.aspx):

```
var basicProperties = await folder.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
var dateModified = basicProperties.DateModified;
```